# How to find the parent initialization of a variable of a function using clang ast?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-static-analyzer, clang-ast-matchers

Hi so I'm able to match function calls using ASTMatchers. But I need to find the statement where one of the parameters of this function has been initialized. How do I do that?

```
int main(){
char* str = "abcde";
char dest[19];
size_t len = strlen(str);
strncpy(dest,str,len+1);
}
```

In the above example I found the call to `strncpy` and I need to find the initialization for `len` which should point to `strlen`.

Is there any way to do it using Clang?
Thanks.